# jQuery Slideup/Down Append Question

Tags: jquery

```
$(".item").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).slideDown().append(
            $("<div class=\"attending\">Yes/No</div>")
        );
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("div:last").slideUp().remove();
  }
);
```

I am using the above code to append a div onto the bottom of an element when rolled over. I have a number of .item divs, each one getting it appended to them on rollover, but for some reason I am unable to make the slidedown/up work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$(".item").hover(
    function () {
        var answer = $("<div class=\"attending\">Yes/No</div>").hide();
        answer.appendTo($(this)).slideDown();
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).find("div:last").slideUp("normal", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
);
```

### It doesn't slide down!

You appended the wrong child to the wrong element and you forgot to hide the element first.

### It doesn't slide up!

This line starts sliding up, but doesn't wait for the animation to finish and removes the element.

```
$(this).find("div:last").slideUp().remove()
```

Comment: This one has it. The .remove() needs to be called as part of a callback function in the .slideUp(). Otherwise they run at the same time. The callback ensures the removal won't occur until the animation ends.

Comment: Is there a way to require the cursor be over the element for more than 2 seconds or so?

Comment: Yes, through Javascript's setTimeout(). It's not directly implemented in jQuery. I suggest you ask in another question.

Comment: I've seen other solutions for this problem, but this is the most elegant. Giving a +1.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively I'm giong to say that you're claling the slide effect on the wrong element. It's being called on `.list` rather than `div.attending`, which is the box I presume you want to appear.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(".item").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append(
        $("<div class=\"attending\">Yes/No</div>").hide();
    ).find("div:last").slideDown();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("div:last").slideUp("normal", function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Doesn't slide at all. Just instant appear/disappear

Comment: The above answer has the correct version (not my answer). My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar prob. was using **.append()**; tried with callback functions- but didn't work at all. 
 So, had done a trick and succeeded. Take a **brief** look.
 here are the steps-

- while appending contents; take a variable and keep its value incrementing whenever the append-function-block gets called.
  Setting an id with that variable for that element and keeping that hided.

`function add_more_charge()

{

var i  = $("#store_id_value").val();

var id = 'some_id_'+i;

var str= '<div style="display:none" id="'+id+'">...............</div>';

$("#store_id_value").val(++i);

$("#additional_charges").append(str);

$("#"+id).slideDown();

}`

here, within this- `<input type="hidden" id="store_id_value" value="2" />`
a value is stored, and incremented in every call.

We can generate random numbers. Use of global variables will be a good option too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".item").hover(
  function () {
    var content = $(this).append($("<div class=\"attending\">Yes/No</div>")).hide();
    $('.attending').last().slideDown();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find(".attending").last().slideUp("normal", function() {
      $(this).remvove();
    });
  }
);
```

Try this it's bit hackish but does its work.